# Can I enter New Zealand again after receiving a tourist visa last March?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, new-zealand

I am very much interested to know if I can travel again to New Zealand after I went there last March this year.
I'm planning to visit again next year, this time it's on a business trip sponsored by my Kiwi clients.

I am a Filipino and stayed for 2 weeks.

This is the thing I'm concerned about: We usually only allow visitors to stay for nine months in an 18-month period. https://www.immigration.govt.nz/knowledgebase/kb-question/kb-question-3816

Comment: You can stay for 9 months in an 18 month period, and you only stayed for 2 weeks.  I think you're fine as you're nowhere near the 9 month stay limit

Comment: @Midavalo so is it safe to say that I can apply for another visitor visa for next year?

Comment: @coco I don't see any issue with it, but I don't know for sure (I am from New Zealand originally so I've never needed to apply for a visa).  Was your visa single-entry or is it valid for multiple entries or a set amount of time?

Comment: @Midavalo it is only single-entry visa.

Comment: @Coco I believe you're safe to apply again, but as I say above I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Midavalo I think it's better if I apply for a business visitor visa since the nature of my travel is for business work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not worry, since your original tourist visa is now void since you have departed New Zealand and returned home.

You are taking the correct steps in applying for a business visitor visa, since the nature of your next trip is for business purposes.

Just keep in mind the requirements for such a visa. According to the [NZ Immigration official website for business visitor visas](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/business-visitors-visa):

> ### Business reasons
>
> Visitors coming to New Zealand for less than 3 months
>   may be granted a Business Visitor Visa for any of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - to carry out an official trade mission recognised by the New Zealand government
> - to sell goods and services in New Zealand
> - to buy New Zealand goods and services
> - to negotiate or discuss the set-up, expansion or wind-up of a business in New Zealand
> - to carry out any business with the authorised representatives of an overseas company, body or person.
> - To carry out any other work activities, or stay longer than 3 months, you'll need to apply for a work visa.

To answer your question:

> Can I enter New Zealand again after receiving a tourist visa last March?

Yes, you can re-enter New Zealand on new (business visitor) visa. The 9 month stay limit is only for tourist visas, while the business visitor visa allows only 3 month stay limit. These are different visas with different rules. Luckily, you have stayed within the rules on your tourist visa, and are eligible for future visas in NZ.

Comment: Thank you Aussie for answering my question! I appreciate it :)